# Using static cells without a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom view controller that contains a `UIView` and a `UITableView`. So I cannot embed the table view in a `UITableViewController`. (I have read several posts stating that static cells only work in conjunction with a `UITableViewController`.) Furthermore, as I want my app to be compatible with iOS 5 I cannot make use of a container view.

Can I still use static cells in my table view with some trick (in order to design the cells directly in Interface Builder)?
How?

Comment: No, as the other posts have said, you MUST have your table view in a `UITableViewController` in order for it to work with static cells.  You have to use dynamic cells if you use a `UIViewController` instead.

Comment: "I have read several posts stating that static cells only work in conjunction with a UITableViewController" It's even worse than that. Static cells work only in a UITableViewController *in a storyboard*.